# Start Process as other user safely

Tags: c#

I need to disable starting new processes from application through file dialog box. 
I start new process in my application with:

```
psi.StartInfo.UserName = "xxx";
psi.StartInfo.Password = x;
psi.StartInfo.FileName = "xxx";
psi.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.Start();
```

**My problem is that users can open non allowed applications by executing it from file dialog box with permission as psi object**.

right click in file dialog:

[image]

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: Question is how to disable transmit permission from run application. If I start notepad.exe as admin in my code, user can click to "open" and then run with rightclick every aplication with the same permissions as notepad.exe... and this is problem...

Comment: From my knowledge, the common file open/save dialogs use the Windows Explorer. I know no programmatic way to disable program execution, file deletion, directory creation etc. You can create and use a custom file open dialog form to prevent such operations. Another way is to restrict the program execution by group policies. Depends on your requirements...

Comment: You could create a whitelist of valid applications that may be executed by your program.

Comment: If your program itself acquired UAC elevation then there is no mechanism to execute another program from yours without it.  Just don't elevate.

Comment: Option 1) The user has admin rights and can already launch any application as administrator. Option 2) The user does not have admin rights. An admin provided their credentials at the UAC prompt and now that program is running as that user. If this is an Option 2 scenario, the problem is that the Admin is apparently just leaving the user and trusting them, even though they're now running under the Admin credentials. That's a **people** problem, not a technical one.